# jquery contains not working for me

Tags: jquery

I am trying to remove the td , if the span contains a specific letter.

https://jsfiddle.net/zqu3eqfm/42/

I also set up a fiddle showing div working to remove text, but td not
https://jsfiddle.net/zqu3eqfm/134/

Is it possible within the variable , to use td.player has(.warning):contains(S) , i tried that but didn't work

```
var donotcountS = 'td.player:has(span:contains("S"))';
```

Tried above and didn't work

```
var donotcountS = 'td.player:contains(S)';
var donotcountI = 'td.player:contains(I)';
var donotcountO = 'td.player:contains(O)';

$('body').find("td.player:not("+donotcountS+"):not("+donotcountI+"):not("+donotcountO+")").remove()
```

I can not change the td.player in the function , as rest of my script looks for td.player and not td.player span , so i need to make the change in the variables that will make it work.

```
<td class="player"><a>REMOVE ALL TD 1</a>  (<span class="warning">S</span>)</td>
<td class="player"><a>SHOW ME 1</a>  (<span class="warning">T</span>)</td>
<td class="player"><a>REMOVE ALL TD  2</a>  (<span class="warning">O</span>)</td>
<td class="player"><a>SHOW ME 2</a></td>
<td class="player"><a>SHOW ME 3</a></td>
<td class="player"><a>S</a>  (<span class="warning">SHOW ME 4</span>)</td>
<td class="player"><a>REMOVE ALL TD  3</a>  (<span class="warning">I</span>)</td>
```

Also , I really would like to make each of those var , so i can set them to true or false , so i can decide on which page i load the script whether or not to turn any of them off or on.

Comment: `td.player` , does not has class warning. I'm deleting my answer since I don't know what' you're really after.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT:

I have added this in your jsfiddle:

```
var item = $('.warning');
for (var i = 0; i <= item.length; i++) {
    if ($(item[i]).text() == 'S' || $(item[i]).text() == 'I' || $(item[i]).text() == 'O') {
        $(item[i]).parent().remove();      
    }
}
```

I think the code, should already be clear for you :)

Here is the link: https://jsfiddle.net/zqu3eqfm/210/

Comment: Yes you are right, sorry I didn't read it well hehe. But now I have edited my code. Now it only checks if it contains a S, I or O. If the item containts that, then he will remove it.

Comment: I have edited my code again. Now it deletes the td tag. You had forgotten to add a row and a table. That was the reason that I couldn't delete the td tag. Also why have I a -1 for my answer xD?